# Reset index after groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas

```
by_month =  df_omsk_last_year.groupby(df_omsk_last_year.index.month, as_index=False).agg({'T': ['mean', 'min', 'max']})
by_month = by_month.reset_index()
by_month = by_month.rename(columns={'mean':'mean__'})
by_month.info()
by_month['mean__']
```

I have key error, of course.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 12 entries, 0 to 11
Data columns (total 4 columns):
(index, )      12 non-null int64
(T, mean__)    12 non-null float64
(T, min)       12 non-null float64
(T, max)       12 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1)
memory usage: 464.0 bytes
```

What I should do? I have tried a lot of ways.

index is datetime, T is float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `MultiIndex in columns` with same level `T`. You can prevent it by specify column after `groupby` for processing:

```
df_omsk_last_year = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'T':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

}, index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=6, freq='10D'))

by_month = (df_omsk_last_year.groupby(df_omsk_last_year.index.month.rename('month'))['T']
                              .agg(['mean', 'min', 'max'])
                              .rename(columns={'mean':'mean__'})
                              .reset_index())
print (by_month)
   month  mean__  min  max
0      1     7.0    4    9
1      2     2.5    2    3
```

Or by [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
by_month =  (df_omsk_last_year.groupby(df_omsk_last_year.index.month)
                              .agg(mean__=('T', 'mean'),
                                   min__=('T', 'min'),
                                   max__=('T', 'max'))
                              .reset_index())
```